# Laravel 5.8 redirect back with message not passing the message to the front end

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.8

I have a controller with this redirect at the end of a method:

```
    // Setup Response message
    $msg = [
        'type' => 'success',
        'value' => 'Your action was successful',
    ];

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', $msg);
```

The response looks like this:

```
array:5 [▼
  "_flash" => array:2 [▶]
  "_token" => "stMmai4OuWI2QlhYGNzxSDyb1qINLfD3RWsoM8mx"
  "_previous" => array:1 [▶]
  "url" => []
  "login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d" => 2
]
```

I am stumped as to what is causing the message to not be flashed through to session.

If I do this:

```
session()->flash('message', $msg);

dd(session()->all()); 

    // Setup Response message
    $msg = [
        'type' => 'success',
        'value' => 'Your action was successful',
    ];

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', $msg);
```

prior to the redirect, the session contains the message.

I even moved the two routes (POST and GET) outside of all Auth groups / Middleware, same result.

What could be clearing the session message?

Comment: please can you try `return redirect()->back()->with($msg);`

Comment: Hi @dparoli, no difference. Could this be a NGINX setting issue?

Comment: This should pass the variable $msg to the view but not the session

Comment: @TheRealPapa, `session()->flash()` does same thing as  `session()->put()`  only that it makes the session only available to the next request.

Comment: I looked in the source and the RedirectResponse has a function with() that flash data in the session, so it should work. It probably depends on you session storage or server configuration.

Comment: Yes, I know it should work. Question is why is it not on this very project (it works in others). Could this be an NGINX setting?

Comment: The problem could be with the new update Laravel 5.8. Your code doesn't work in my machine also. You can see my answer update

Comment: Hey Udo, you were right! I did `php artisan optimize:clear` and then with `redirect()->back()->with('message', $msg);` it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@Udo was right, it seems a change in Laravel 5.8. This worked:

```
redirect()->back()->with('message', $msg);
```

Comment: Glad to know it now works. My answer gave more insight. Though it wasn't to the point - that's why I deleted it.

Comment: @TheRealPapa so this worked only after you did php artisan optimize:clear?

Answer (score 0):

A better way of flashing data to the current session is using the global `session()` helper. Using this method your code should look like this:

```
    $msg = [
        'type' => 'success',
        'value' => 'Your action was successful',
    ];

    session()->put('message', $msg);
    return redirect()->back();
```

**NOTE**:

Redirecting back using `with(['message' => $msg])` passes the variable `$message` to a **view** or **route**. So you can access it using that variable name in the view you redirected to.

On the other hand, using either `session()->put('message', $msg);` or `session()->flash('message', $msg);` both flashes the data with key `message` into the current **user session**. So you can access the session data using `session()->get('message')`

**UPDATE**:

From my research, As of Laravel version 5.8, I think `withInput()` is now reserved for **Request data** (that is data pass to your controller via `GET` or `POST` request) and `with()` is reserved for passing data to a **route** or **view**  either through `route($route)->with()` or `view($view)->with()`.

So the issue with your code may be changes in the new update - version 5.8

Comment: Hi @Udo, no difference

Comment: Hi Udo, I have done this foryears working with my syntax. On this particular project it is not. So the question is what could be the cause. Your suggesting is to manually set session when Laravel has the method for this.

Comment: `withInput()` flash data to the **session** not to the **view**

Comment: @dparoli, you are right. But I shouldn't have used it at all for any other data apart from GET or POST Request data. See my update.

Comment: with() and withInput() are both defined on the RedirectResponse class they are not limited to route or view

Comment: Just putting this back up for reference purposes... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `return redirect()->back()-withErrors('message', $msg)`

EDIT: You use the ErrorBag here - maybe this works as it seems something is killing your session flash.

regards
Jens

Comment: Please explain: where did you find that with() doesn't work with back()?

Comment: Normally it should work - i should have been more precise - you are right. What i wanted to say was that if he uses withErrors() he uses a different way (ErrorBag). He can see if something is clearing is session flash...

Comment: @TheRealPapa: Are you using DebugBar in your dev env? Could you see your message over there?

Comment: Yes Debugbar is showing the session without the message, per my dd above. The question is what could be wiping it?

Comment: Hi @jtwes, thenks for the help. This is what worked in the end: `redirect()->back()->with('message', $msg);`

Comment: Thanks. So the problem was a cached view or config? beacuse artisan optimize:clear helped?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues, and my code looked like below, I previously had a database operation in the try cache block, I removed and the data passed was no longer working, After numerous trials, I realized I have DB transactions, so I removed them and the session/flash data `redirect()->back()->with($inputArray);` started working

```
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            if ($coupon == null) {
                $this->results['failure'] = __('messages.failure_coupon_is_invalid');
                return redirect()->back()->with($this->results);
            }

            setHasDiscount($coupon);
            $this->results['success'] = __('messages.success_coupon_applied');
            DB::commit();

            return redirect()->back()->with($this->results);
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            DB::rollBack();
            $this->results['failure'] = $exception->getMessage();
            return redirect()->back()->with($this->results);
        }
```